# Getting letter from loaded text

Tags: javascript

I have a code. It loads text from this:

```
<script type="text/mygamelevel" id="level1" src="levels/level1.txt">
        000122341
        124235245
        154456567
</script>

mapa = loadFromFile("level1");
```

And loadFromFile:

```
function loadFromFile(id) {
var level = document.getElementById(id).text;
var lines = level.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    if (!line.trim())
        continue;
    var letter = line.charAt(2);
    alert("Second: " + letter + " ");
}
}
```

But it doesn't work :/ Alert in browser is empty.
Why?

Comment: can you precise what is the element retrieved by document.getElementById?  and what is the value of the `level` variable ?

Comment: You should [debug](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/debugger) and see step by step what are your variable values.

Comment: I found why is it wrong. var line looks like ".......0013435535" ("." == [space]). Do you know how to remove spaces from string?

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your function :

```
function loadFromFile(id) {
    var level = document.getElementById(id).text;
    var lines = level.split("\n");
    //lines.length - 1 to parse each lines from 0 to 8 (9 numbers)
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
        var line = lines[i].trim(); //trim to remove white spaces
        if(line.length)  //if the line is not empty
        {
            var letter = line.charAt(1); //second letter
           alert("Second: " + letter + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that an array starts to `0`, so the second letter is the `charAt(1)` and you have to count from `0` not from `1` :

`000122341` *=> 9 numbers*

`for 1 to 10` *=> 9 numbers*

`for 0 to 10` *=> 10 numbers*

`for 0 to (10 - 1)` *=> 9 numbers*

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/4j73X/1/) for a working example !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable `line` contains space at the beginning it is like `..000122`  (where each dot is a space) you need to remove those extra spaces to get the value you want.